# How to measure the polynomial runtime?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, polynomials

I'm doing complexity analysis problems. I have to find the polynomials (e.g. `5n^2 + 2n + 2`) and big-O of the methods. I'm doing the following one:

```java
public static int[][] method(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    int ra = a.length;
    int ca = a[0].length;
    int cb = b[0].length;
    int[][] c = new int[ra][cb];

    for(int i = 0; i < ra; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cb; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < ca; k++) {
                c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I have already counted some of the operations that happen in this method, but I can't really tell what `n` would be here. I'm thinking about `(ra * ca) + (b.length * cb)`, but I'm not sure if that could be the input n. If it is, how can I know how many times the outermost loop is running, for example? `n/4`?

Comment: (Hey, it’s matrix multiplication.) There’s no single, definitive answer to this. You could define l, m, n to be the number of rows of `a`, the number of columns of `a` = the number of rows of `b`, and the number of columns of `b` respectively, and call it Θ(l * m * n), for example.

Comment: `(ra * ca) + (b.length * cb)` That's some unusual thinking.